# Why doesn't my promise resolves?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have the following function which resizes images.

The `promise` should resolve in `onload` part of my code, however it doesn't for some reason...

```
import Pica from 'pica';

const pica = new Pica();

export default ({ src, size }) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const [width, height] = size.split('x');
    const from = new Image();
    const to = document.createElement('canvas');
    const options = {
      width,
      height,
    };

    from.onload = async () => {
      try {
        const canvas = await pica.resize(from, to, options);
        resolve(canvas);
      } catch (e) {
         reject(e);
      }
    };

    from.src = src;
  });
```

I use this function with to get an array of different-sized versions of one image. I'm using `Promise.all()` to achieve this.

Here's my code where I'm calling this function:

```
    ...
    const img = ...
    sizes.map(size => {
      promisesArray.push(resizeImage({ img, size }));
    });

    Promise.all(promisesArray).then(data => console.log(data))
```

I've tried to `console.log(resizeImage({ img, size }))`, and got promise with a `pending` status which does not resolve.

I've also had an assumption that it was due to `Pica`. So I tried to simplify the function, but it didn't work either:

```
// no extra code
export default ({ src, size }) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
    const from = new Image();

    from.onload = () => {
      // what's wrong here?
      resolve('hello');
    };

    from.src = src;
  });
```

Comment: That has to work. Is there any other code on the page? Maybe `onload` gets overriden

Comment: Is the `onload` handler getting called?

Comment: @JonasW. I don't think that `onload` gets overriden. The function that resizes images gets called from my `react` component

Comment: @sklingler93 seems like it's not... I've tried to do `console.log` inside `onload` which didn't show anything in the console

Comment: `console.log(resizeImage({ img, size }))` will always result in a pending promise, it's a matter of timing. Try something like `resizeImage({src, size}).then(()=> console.log("something"))`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to listing for `onload` you should always add a listener for `onerror` since it's possible that the `Image` will fail to load.

If you add a `console.log` into the `onerror` callback I suspect you will see that you've passed in an invalid `src` to one or more of your calls and the image is simply failing to load.

As an example demonstrating how to wire up the `onerror` callback (ignoring your resizing code which appears unrelated to your issues):

```js
const loadImg = (src) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const img = new Image();

  img.onload = () => resolve(img);
  img.onerror = (err) => reject(err);

  img.src = src;
});

// This should succeed
loadImg('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7').then(
  () => console.log('Image loaded!'),
  () => console.log('Image failed!'),
);

// This will fail
loadImg('invalid-url').then(
  () => console.log("How did that load?"),
  () => console.log("That wasn't an image!"),
);
```